# how to disable office.js addin for not supported emails like (delivery failures)

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I sent an email to an invalid emailaddress and it bounce back as delivery failed. office.js add-in activation buttons are not displayed on the delivery failed emails but the pinnable add-in is still displayed. When you are positioned on the delivery failed email `office.context.mailbox.item` returns the previous items details. Is there anyway for add-in to find out the current email is not supported and display a message to user or block any user actions?

Comment: Not sure but can you inspect the item’s type (message class) and conditionally disable controls? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/forms/item-types-and-message-classes - this is a vba reference but I’d expect the classification to be same for web addins

Comment: as mentioned in the post. Item is returning previous email details, so item's type is not accurate. it's probably a bug in office.js

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Ah yes I see! Agree with @BrianClink it looks like a bug

Comment: The pane should display an error message in this case. I have verified the bug. However, as an add-in developer you should get a "null" item event in your ItemChanged event callback, and can detect when this happens. Also Office.context.mailbox.item will be set to NULL.

Comment: Running some sample code like:  
Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(
    Office.EventType.ItemChanged,
 
    function (eventArgs)    // event handler
    {
        showMessage(JSON.stringify(eventArgs));
       showMessage(JSON.stringify(Office.context.mailbox.item));
         
    },
 
    function (asyncResult) {}
);

Comment: returns: null
{"type":"olkItemSelectedChanged","initialData":null,"itemNumber":{"itemNumber":0}} Are you seeing a different result?

Comment: when you are positioned on a valid email and switch to delivery failure email, Office.context.mailbox.item is returning previous valid email details for me.

Comment: I tested this in Outlook Desktop, Outlook WebAccess (Classic/Non Beta) and Outlook Web Access (beta). 

In Outlook Desktop, the mailbox.item is NULL, but no error page is displayed. In OWA (Non Beta), the mailbox.item is the OLD ITEM. no Error Page is displayed
In OWA (Beta), the error page is displayed.

Comment: So on Outlook Desktop you should be able to check for the NULL item. (the bug about the error page not showing has been put on our backlog). In OWA (non-beta)... you may just want to switch to OWA beta where the bug has been fixed (if possible)

Comment: Thanks for testing and confirming